How is this op amp in negative feedback?
I'm trying to solve this question for homework but they mentioned the first op amp is in negative feedback. How though?
Is it because of the output of the second op amp (OA2) is also in negative feedback and the output's signal is the opposite of the other input signal (Vi) in the first op amp?


Is this that "adding a minus" (output of the second amp entering the +) is the same as "subtracting a plus" (output going into the - of the first amp)?

If the output of OA1 goes up, the output of OA2 goes down (OA1 and R1/R2 form an inverting amplifier) and a fraction of that voltage goes to the non inverting input of OA1 (tending to counteract the output going up), so yes OA1 has negative feedback.
That does not mean it's stable, however.

Here's a simple, arbitrary system whose output is \$V_{OUT}\$, which is being modified somehow by the "?" block to produce \$V_{FB}\$, and \$V_{FB}\$ is applied to one of the inputs so that it may further influence the output:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Clearly, if \$V_{FB}\$ were to rise, so would \$V_{OUT}\$, and vice versa, since \$V_{FB}\$ is applied to the non-inverting op-amp input. You might assume that feedback to the non-inverting input means that feedback must be positive, unstable, but that's premature. Everything depends on what's in the "?" box.
If \$V_{OUT}\$ were to change, and via feedback through "?" that change would cause \$V_{FB}\$ to change in the same direction, then you have positive feedback. Any small change in \$V_{OUT}\$ would be "reinforced", exacerbated, and the output would go rushing off uncontrolled to some extreme.
If a change in \$V_{OUT}\$ would cause \$V_{FB}\$ to change in the opposite direction, which opposes the initial perturbation of \$V_{OUT}\$, then you have negative feedback. The consequence is that the output does not shoot off to an extreme, but rather settles at whatever value is necessary to produce a stable equilibrium. Usually this equilibrium is when \$V_{FB}=V_{IN}\$.
By those arguments, in my schematic above, for feedback to be negative, resulting in stability, we require a rise in \$V_{OUT}\$ to cause a fall in \$V_{FB}\$, and vice versa. In other words, as long as the "?" block inverts, you have negative feedback.
In your own schematic, OA2 is configured as an inverting amplifier, which fits that description, and therefore feedback is indeed negative.
If we were to swap the inverting and non-inverting inputs in my example above, then things would be different:

simulate this circuit
Now, for feedback to be negative, we require \$V_{FB}\$ to change in the same direction as \$V_{OUT}\$, since a rise in \$V_{FB}\$ always results in a fall of \$V_{OUT}\$ (and vice versa).
Don't let the fact that feedback is applied to the non-inverting input fool you. All this tells you is that there is feedback, but not whether it's negative or positive. To know which type of feedback it is, you must determine if a perturbation in output would result in feedback that opposes that perturbation (negative), or further exacerbates it (positive).
Here are some examples of negative feedback. The first is the simple follower, where the output is tied directly to the inverting input:

simulate this circuit
Since \$V_{FB}=V_{OUT}\$, a rise/fall in \$V_{OUT}\$ would oppose itself, so feedback is negative. As I mentioned, the equilibrium established with negative feedback is \$V_{FB}=V_{IN}\$, and consequently the follower does this:
$$ V_{OUT} = V_{IN} $$
If we replace the "?" block with a simple \$\times (-1)\$, we would have the situation \$V_{FB}=-V_{OUT}\$:

simulate this circuit
For a change in \$V_{OUT}\$ to oppose itself via feedback, I have had to attach feedback to the non-inverting input. That's because a rise in \$V_{OUT}\$ causes a fall in \$V_{FB}\$, and vice versa. The same equilibrium arises, \$V_{FB}=V_{IN}\$, so:
$$ V_{OUT} = -V_{FB} = -V_{IN} $$
Lastly, some attenuation and inversion in the feedback path:

simulate this circuit
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{FB} &= V_{OUT} \times \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} \times (-1) \\ \\
&= -\frac{1}{3} V_{OUT} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
With a rise in \$V_{OUT}\$ causing a fall in \$V_{FB}\$, the signal is already inverted, so it must be applied to the non-inverting op-amp input in order for feedback to oppose changes in \$V_{OUT}\$. The same equilibrium is achieved:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{FB} &= V_{IN} \\ \\
V_{IN} &= -\frac{1}{3} V_{OUT} \\ \\
V_{OUT} &= -3V_{IN}
\end{aligned}
$$
To solve your homework problem, you need to identify IN, FB and OUT, and find the relationship between \$V_{FB}\$ and \$V_{OUT}\$, which is all about OA2 and the resistors around it, which form the "?" block. Then apply the "ideal op-amp with negative feedback" rule that \$V_{FB}=V_{IN}\$.

When there is one (or three or...) sign inversion(s) within a feedback loop we have negative feedback. And it does not matter if such a negative sign appears at the input of the (main) amplifier or anywhere within the loop.
However, such a configuration with two opamps within a common loop will decrease the stability margin because both parasitic phase shifts are added.
One application of such a configuration is - for example - the so called "positive phase-lead integrator" when R3 is replaced with a capacitor and the grounded node of R4 is used as an input.

What is this circuit for?
We know there are two main types of op-amp circuits with negative feedback: non-inverting and inverting. They differ in the way the output voltage (or part of it) is subtracted from the input voltage: for non-inverting circuits, this is done in series, while for inverting circuits, it is done in parallel. For this reason, non-inverting circuits have a high input impedance, while inverting circuits have a relatively low input impedance.
However, what is surprising is that when looking at this strange circuit, which is inverting (because the input voltage is applied to the inverting input of OA1), part of the output voltage is fed back in series, as in a non-inverting circuit! What the heck is it made this way?
Building the circuit
Let's try to understand this by building the circuit step by step.
Op-amp follower
First, we decide to force an op-amp that amplifies more than 100,000 times...

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
... to amplify only once!?! For this purpose, we take the entire output voltage and subtract it in series manner from the input, thus forcing it to follow the input voltage (note that the op-amp is flipped vertically compared to the one in your schematic).

simulate this circuit

Non-inverting amplifier
Then, seeing the absurdity of a unity gain -:), we take only (1/2) of the output voltage and feed it back to the input, forcing the op-amp to increase its output voltage (twice compared to the input). The R3-R4 voltage divider can be considered as a disturbance that the op-amp compensates for by doubling its output voltage. So, a non-inverting amplifier can be considered as a "disturbed voltage follower".

simulate this circuit

Buffered non-inverting amplifier
Then, perhaps to mitigate the loading effect of the 100-ohm resistors, we decide to add a unity-gain buffer (OA2 op-amp follower) at the output. However, the circuit remains a non-inverting amplifier...

simulate this circuit

"Inverting non-inverting amplifier"
So, to make it inverting, we replace the follower with an inverter (R1, R2, and OA2) and flip OA1 back to its original orientation (swap its inputs).

simulate this circuit


OA2 forms an inverting amplifier and, in effect, this makes the non-inverting input of OA1 suitable for negative feedback via OA2.

Note that if rr is too low (rr < 1kOhm) ... there is some "stuff".
Here is what happens. (Blue curve is left to right)

With stepping the square pulse regularly ... hysteresis appears at 2 V.

